# How to dynamically add image in email merge template?

Tags: email-template, mail-merge

I was trying to add image in the mail merge template I follow this link to add image in the doc page [here](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000229801&language=en_US).

But when I select the mail merge template which I was created it show success message, but nothing happens: no email, no document created in docs folder.

Any help will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide details about which email temaplte you're using? I've recently used email templates. Thought I can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It working fine I make little mistake.I do something like this
Hello «Account_Name»
Image is here «IMAGE:ACCOUNT_IMAGE_URL__c»
Thanks.

But In mail merge Custom Field  is map like this:-

Hello «Account_Name»
Image is here «IMAGE:ACCOUNT_IMAGE_URL»
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the quick response.

It working fine now. I make little mistake to mapping custom field .I do something like this

```
Hello «Account_Name»
Image is here «IMAGE:ACCOUNT_IMAGE_URL__c»
Thanks.
```

But In mail merge Custom field is map like this:-

```
Hello «Account_Name»
Image is here «IMAGE:ACCOUNT_IMAGE_URL»
Thanks.
```